# Convert dot notation to bracket notation in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to use dynamic columns in primeng table. However, in order to do so, column fields are required in bracket notation. I have one column that has nested JSON structure. I don't know how to write that in bracket notation. Please Help. Thanks in advance:

My JSON:

```
[
    {
        "studentName": "test",
        "email": null,
        "phnNumber": 1,
        "subjects": [
            {
                "subjectName": "Maths",
                "subjectTeacher": "Elon"
            },
            {
                "subjectName": "English",
                "subjectTeacher": "Shakespeare"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "studentName": "test2",
        "email": null,
        "phnNumber": 1,
        "subjects": [
            {
                "subjectName": "CS",
                "subjectTeacher": "Elon"
            },
            {
                "subjectName": "English",
                "subjectTeacher": "Shakespeare"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My typescipt:

```
this.cols = [
      { field: 'studentName', header: 'Student Name' },
      { field: 'email', header: 'Email' },
      { field: 'phnNumber', header: 'Contact No' },
      { field: '["subjects"][0]["subjectName"]', header: 'Subject Name' }

    ];
```

My template:

```
     <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-student let-columns="columns">

                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{student[col.field]}}
                </td>
</ng-template>
```

In dot notation, if I have to access the 1st subject of student 1  I'll do `students[0].subjects[0].subjectname` where a student is an array of the student. How can I replicate this in bracket notation?

Comment: `students[0]["subjects"][0]["subjectname"]`

Comment: I added what you suggested to my columns array.I'm not able to get the subject value in my table.Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
students[i]['subjects'][j]['subjectName']
```

For first subject of the first student,

```
students[0]['subjects'][0]['subjectName']
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt1yt5

Comment: hi I added what you suggested to my columns array.I'm not able to get the subject value in my table.Please see my updated question

Comment: @rock11 Can you create a stackblitz demo? And may I ask why you want bracket instead of dots?

Comment: I just want to dynamically load that column in my primeng table.For some reason it's not working with dot notation.

Comment: @rock11 Your demo is working fine according to your specs. What is the issue now?

Comment: The issue is that I'm unable to filter the table based on the data present in the Grade 1 column

Comment: can you please help me with this.

Comment: @rock11 Each student will have only value for each grade right? Then why do you have it in an array? If you can flatten into an object, I think it will be possible.

Comment: @rock11 Is the number of grades for each student fixed? If so, which are they?

Comment: Number of grades is fixed. Each student can have 2 grades- grade 1 and 2. Since I am showing only grade 1 in the table, I want to filter the data based on grade1. Filter is working for all columns except this one.Also the data is coming from backend I can't flatten it .

Comment: @rock11 The current JSON schema you're using is wrong in my opinion. But if you can't change it from backend, then let it be. Instead you can format the data in the client side to a more flattened way and use it in table. See this demo [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxtq7v](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxtq7v) in which I have formatted the data and your requirements are met.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about doing the same.I'll go with formatting the data at client side.Thanks a lot man